# Phone Clone from Samsung S7 to Huawei P30 blocked?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, huawei-p20

I'm trying to upgrade a Samsung S7 to a Huawei P30 using the Phone Clone app on the P30.

This works by setting up a WiFi hotspot on the new device and then connecting the old device to it.

This fails every time, but when I look at the old S7 the hotspot has been added to the list of restricted networks, probably because the new phone isn't acting as a bridge to the internet and something stupid in the S7 is deciding it isn't a valid network because no internet.

How do I get Phone Clone to work?

How do I turn off whatever it is in the Samsung phone deciding to block the WiFi hotspot because it's local only?

Comment: afaik Samsung have Knox enabled by default which may prevent access to phone data (regardless it is hard to believe such apps are working without root?) but i am still learning...

Comment: @alecxs it doesn't get that far and I've given Phone Clone access to the things I want it to copy. It's failing to connect in the first place.

Comment: didn't know that such app exist. unfortunately only for huawei - would like to see it for other devices too